# Xcode ipa installs on iOS 5.1,but fails on iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

we created an ipa file with Xcode 4.3.1 keeping SDK 5.1 and 
deployment target as iOS 4.0 .
the app installs on iphone with iOS 5.1,4.0 ,But fails to install on iOS 5.1.1

Anybody knows the solution let us know

Regards,
Reshma

Comment: Can you post console log, XCode -> Organizer -> Devices -> select your iOS 5.1.1 device under Devices -> Console. Look for your app related info there.

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely your 5.1.1 device UDID is not included to the provisioning profile, the .ipa with target SDK 5.1 (actually with any supported SDK which is iOs 3.0 at lowest) should be OK with 5.1.1 devices. Otherwise, please give more details of the installation process.