# Is it possible to run iPhone app deployed with 5.0 SDK in iOS 5.1.1 iPad device

Tags: ios

I have build the app using Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS 5.0 SDK target, now i am have iOS 5.1 in my iPad device, what i have to know is, if i upgrade my device to iOS 5.1.1, will my app work. I just googled it, but i can't find solution. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work, it will also work on any ios in the future (ios 6+ etc..)
Please check my answer here [Will my app work with a new iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913662/will-my-app-work-with-a-new-ios/10913684#10913684)

Comment: unless some API's of the older OS versions you are using is deprecated and/or eventually *removed*.

Comment: Which should not happen that easily, when was the last time you saw such a break in the releases?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking of deployment for testing, you need at least Xcode 4.3 (for Lion only) to be able to run your app on a device on iOS 5.1

Comment: Yes, it is true. What i have done is, i just copied the iOS 5.1 SDK from the package content from Xcode 4.3 into Xcode 4.2.1, so now the app is working perfectly in my device (iOS 5.1). Pls let me know if i want to use Xcode 4.3 now to work in iOS 5.1.1 in device.

Comment: According to this post you might have problems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784467/xcode-ipa-installs-on-ios-5-1-but-fails-on-ios-5-1-1

Comment: kindly tell me if there is any solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my app build with Xcode 4.2.1 and 5.1 deployment target, now i can work the app in iOS 5.1.1 installed device. 
**Note :**
Make sure your Xcode have iOS 5.1 SDK Frameworks support.